# Image Array, Calibration for Bullet Time

Tags: opencv, openframeworks

I'm very new to OpenCV and programming in a C language or any language really.

As of right now, in the boundaries of a project I'm working on writing a calibration for multiple images, which will finally be used in a Bullet-Time effect.

In order to calibrate the images, I'm detecting markers (color detection), Then calculate the transformation matrix from my desImg to my srcImg and finally apply the PerpectiveTransform.

This Works find for 2 Images, which I individually load; however, how can I fill and array with images. IPImage * img[] doesnt work.

I need this to get a transformation Matrix for each individual Images so I can use OpenGL in OpenFrameworks to visualize an imagesequence which is calibrated. Within a loop, I would read out Image after Image and compare it to my desImage for calculating the right Matrix.

I dont really want to load tons of IPImages if I dont have to.

Thank you for your help

PS: Tried this also...no luck:

CvMat* images;
images = cvCreateMat(1, 8, IplImage);

Answer (score 0):

First i would recommend you look at python with opencv

The new python bindings (import cv2) make working in python much easier, and you avoid all the complexities of C.  The actual image function calls are still in C so it's just as fast but a lot easier to learn and experiment with.

As to your specific question you need the transforms to be relative to something. Depending on your setup you should either decide to compare each image to the previous one and  have all the shifts relative - or pick some central frame and use that as one of the each pair and calculate all shifts relative to that.

Comment: Yes thats what im planning to do. Yet will have a lot of images that im going to compare to my reference image. However, im trying to have an array with all my images that im going to compare to one reference image. Now how do i load a lot of images into an array so that I can, within my loop, read each image into a IPimage format, which ill need to filter for markers etc.